# Scan error: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *string

Tags: mysql, go

When I try to fetch Articles without photo from mysql database:

```
func ArticlesAllText() ([]Article, error) {
    var err error
    var result []Article
    err = database.SQL.Select(&result, "SELECT * FROM Article WHERE photo IS NULL")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return result, standardizeError(err)
}
```

I get

> sql: Scan error on column index 10: unsupported Scan, storing
>   driver.Value type  into type *string

When the field value is `NULL`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I personally don't allow nulls in my DB when the main interfacing language is Go. I purposefully normalize the DB such that this is possible. I realize this isn't applicable to everyone, so it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `sql.NullString`.

https://godoc.org/database/sql#NullString

Personally, I hate this solution, which is why I normalize my DB so that there are no `NULL`s.

Either change

```
var result []Article
```

To

```
var result []sql.NullString
```

Then take those results and make a `[]Article` using the checks from the documentation.

Or in your struct, change

```
Photo *string
```

To

```
Photo sql.NullString
```

And deal with the annoyance of it being a struct instead of a `*string`

Thanks to ATN, see here for a guide https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-i-handled-null-possible-values-from-database-rows-in-golang-521fb0ee267

Comment: So how would you rewrite the query above?

Comment: @Karlom The query is the same, you just use a `sql.NullString` field instead of `*string` in the `interface{}` you pass to it to populate.

Comment: Please provide the code. I'm unable to follow your instructions.

Comment: In more details: https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-i-handled-null-possible-values-from-database-rows-in-golang-521fb0ee267

Comment: @ATN Thanks for that, I'll include it in the answer, though I still personally advocate for non-null databases, I realize their usefulness in determining if a value was set or if a zero value was actually the real value.

Comment: While marshaling JSON gives you the following `"updated_at": {"String": "","Valid": false}` how do I set it null?

Answer (score 9):

You can use any of the below two solutions:-

1. You can use `sql.NullString` to handle the field before using scan(). OR
2. You can replace all the possible `NULL` values with the desired string say `''` from the query itself.

For implementing the 1st solution refer to the @RayfenWindspear answer.
For the 2nd solution update the query as below:-

```
SELECT colm1, colm2, COALESCE(photo, '') photo, colm4 FROM Article WHERE photo IS NULL
```

**For MySQL** use `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function to return an alternative value if an expression is NULL:

**For SQL Server** use `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function for the same result

**MS Access** use `IsNull` function for the same result

**For Oracle** use `NVL()` function for the same result

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: yes, coalesce works great for times like this for me!